# Strange issue in Running an application with remote desktop on Windows XP

Tags: desktop, remote

An application that I have runs normally on the local computer, but throws error when running under remote desktop client. Specifically, this is an IDE that refuses to compile code when using it on a computer that is remoted into.

Application: CodeWarrior Development studio for Microcontrollers v6.2 coldfireV1 build 081128

Comment: So... don't do that?

Comment: Is it IDE or the underlying compiler? Can you share what IDE/compiler is it?

Comment: Does it throws error compiling anything or only specific code? (for example accessing local devices of the machine)

Comment: @danielBeck, so what do you recommend when a quick "change and test" is required to the code when you notice something in a lab 3 stories above? This is a cross compiler for an embedded application: specifically "CodeWarrior Development studio for Microcontrollers v6.2 coldfireV1 build 081128.

Comment: @VaibhavGarg Please document the error in the question.

Comment: The only time I saw this problem is with a graphic application because RDP screws with the video driver while connected. Using VNC gets around the problem nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a different remote desktop client?

Instead of using the Windows RDC (That's what i'm assuming you are using) try using a 3rd party remote desktop program such as [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/). It does a much better job of emulating the actual experience of being on the machine than the Windows Client, albeit, the display quality isn't quite as good if you are accessing a machine locally but over the internet they are about the same.

It's free and has solved many headaches that i've had of programs not behaving how they do when I am on physically on the machine. Logmein as their own display adapter which helped me solved some of my issues compiling in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am more interested in knowing WHY that happens, rather than alternatives to what I already have. I will check the alternate suggested, however. But if the server system needs to have this installed, then no dice, as this is not something that can be controlled.